# Times at relativistic speeds

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

Consider an observer $A$ moving in a spaceship at a speed close to $c$, relative to an observer $B$. The $B$ knows that the time on $A$ runs slower, but in the inertial frame of $A$, $B$ is moving away at the same speed close to $c$, while $A$ is stationary. Would $A$ think the time in $B$ is slower?

Comment: Do you expect any other answer than a simple *"Yes"*?

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely YES**!the term "relative to..." tells you everything!

Comment: But if they then compare their clocks, one is going to have a different time than the other, so how would they know if their time is slower or faster?

Comment: So,this is the problem of inertial and non-inertial REFERENCE FRAME,the observer with constant velocity can tell which one is true.A's clock runs slower,here B is sitting in a inertial reference frame,so whatever he says is true.also search for TWIN PARADOX.

Comment: note in case A has acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider an observer $A$ moving in a spaceship at a speed close to $c$, relative to an observer $B$.

Alright.
Moreover, since the motion of $A$ with respect to $B$ is supposed to be characterized by some particular "*speed*" (even if it were not constant) therefore we may assume that $B$ is a member of an **inertial system**; namely having been and having remained **at rest** with respect to suitable additional participants (say observers $K$, $Q$ ...), where, let's say, $A$ moved from $B$ to $K$, then on to $Q$, etc.

In the following let's suppose that the "*speed*" which the members of $B$'s ($K$'s, $Q$'s) inertial system measure of $A$ is a constant: $v_B[~A~]$ which is necessarily smaller than $c$ (the "signal front speed", a.k.a. "speed of light in vacuum"), even though it may be close to $c$.

> $B$ knows that the time on $A$ runs slower

That seems a **nonsense** assertion
("*time on $A$ running slower*" **than** what ??, by which method of comparison ??).

Correct is instead that the comparison of **durations** between $A$ and $B$ can (and, by the setup prescription above typically does) involve the "Lorentz factor" 
$$\sqrt{ 1 - \left( \frac{v_B[~A~]}{c}\right)^2 },$$

a.k.a. "$1/gamma$", whose value is necessarily less than 1. Specificly:

$$ \tau A_{\circ B}^{\circ K} = \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \frac{v_B[~A~]}{c}\right)^2 } ~\times~ \tau B_{\circ A}^{\circledS K \circ A},$$

where

- "$A_{\circ B}$" denotes participant $A$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $B$,
- "$A^{\circ K}$" denotes participant $A$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $K$, and thus
- "$\tau A_{\circ B}^{\circ K}$" denotes $A$'s duration from having been met and passed by participant $B$ until having been met and passed by participant $K$,
- "$B_{\circ A}$" denotes participant $B$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $A$,
- "$B^{\circledS K \circ A}$" denotes participant $B$'s indication **simultaneous to** participant $K$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $A$, and thus
- "$\tau B_{\circ A}^{\circledS K \circ A}$" denotes the duration of $B$ between these two of its indications.

A detailed derivation of this equation can be found [here (PSE/q/110316)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110316/deriving-formula-for-time-dilation/110419#110419).

> but in the inertial frame of $A$

Good!, that's consistent with my above assumption of speed $v_B[~A~]$ being constant.
So, being a member of an inertial frame, $A$ is also **at rest** with respect to suitable additional participants (say observers $J$, $P$ ...), where, let's say, $B$ moved from $A$ to $J$, then on to $P$, etc.

These participants may therefore in turn measure the speed of $B$ (with respect to their, $A$'s, inertial frame): $v_A[~B~]$;
and necessarily it would be found that

$$v_A[~B~] = v_B[~A~],$$

thus both (mutual) speed values being constant.

> $B$ is moving away at the same speed close to $c$, while $A$ is stationary.

Right.

> Would $A$ think the time in $B$ is slower?

Surely, $A$ would not think such nonsense, either;
but, correspondingly to the measurements by $B$ along with $K$ etc., further comparisons between $A$ and $B$ of their durations can be obtained as

$$ \tau B_{\circ A}^{\circ J} = \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \frac{v_A[~B~]}{c}\right)^2 } ~\times~ \tau A_{\circ B}^{\circledS J \circ B},$$

where

- "$B_{\circ A}$" denotes participant $B$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $A$ (as had been mentioned above already),
- "$B^{\circ J}$" denotes participant $B$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $J$, and thus
- "$\tau B_{\circ A}^{\circ J}$" denotes $B$'s duration from having been met and passed by participant $A$ until having been met and passed by participant $J$,
- "$A_{\circ B}$" denotes participant $A$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $B$ (as had been mentioned above already),
- "$A^{\circledS J \circ B}$" denotes participant $A$'s indication **simultaneous to** participant $J$'s indication of having been met and passed by participant $B$, and thus
- "$\tau A_{\circ B}^{\circledS J \circ B}$" denotes the duration of $A$ between these two of its indications.